# Select unique row grouped by column with MySQL

Tags: mysql

My table looks something like:

**ID | Type**
01 | a
02 | c
03 | b
04 | a
05 | b
06 | a

I want to output the *ID* of the last added entries grouped by *Type*. ID is an auto-increment field so the last added entry is obviously the highest number.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `Type` ORDER BY `ID` DESC, `Type` ASC
```

This groups the rows by *Type* then sorts by *ID* so I get IDs 1,2,3 whereas I want to sort first THEN group to get the result: 6,5,2

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? That's important to know if sub-selects would be an option

Comment: MySQL version: 5.0.81-community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for ...

```
SELECT   MAX(`ID`), `Type`
FROM     `table`
GROUP BY `Type`
ORDER BY `Type` ASC
```

read as choose the maximum value of ID for each group of Type.

Comment: Works perfectly. Although the others are solutions, this is the simplest one I was after.

Comment: also noticed, you need to have MAX(`Type`) as well otherwise it doesn't pick the right one, especially if you have a few other columns

Answer (score 1):

If your MySQL version allows subselects (and 5.x does), this should work:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC) AS tmp 
    GROUP BY `type` 
    ORDER BY `type` ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a classic way w/o subselects:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2
  ON (t2.type = t1.type AND t2.id > t1.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

read as "pick rows in the table such that no other row with the same type has a larger id".